# Implicit differentiation: why I cannot multiple both sides by an expression?

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I was solving a problem on implicit differentiation and I was wondering why my answer does not match the given answer. Apparently I multiplied both parts of an equation by an expression to get rid of some fractions before differentiating. Here is my illustration:
Differentiating $$\frac{x}{\sqrt y}+\frac{y}{\sqrt x}=xy$$ we get $$\frac{\sqrt y-\frac{xy'}{2\sqrt y}}{y}+\frac{y'\sqrt x-\frac{y}{2\sqrt x}}{x}=y+xy'$$ or $$y'=\frac{y-\frac{1}{\sqrt y}+\frac{y}{2x\sqrt  x}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt x}-x-\frac{x}{2y\sqrt y}}=\frac{2xy^2\sqrt{xy}-2xy\sqrt x+y^2\sqrt y}{2xy\sqrt y-2x^2y\sqrt {xy} -x^2\sqrt x}$$However if I multiply both parts by $\sqrt{ xy}$ then differentiate $x^{\frac{3}{2}}+y^{\frac{3}{2}}=x^{\frac{3}{2}}y^{\frac{3}{2}}$, the result will be: $$\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{3}{2}y^{\frac{1}{2}}y'=\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{3}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{2}}y'$$ or
$$y'=\frac{y\sqrt{ xy}-\sqrt x}{\sqrt y-x\sqrt{ xy}}$$

Graphing both equations produces the same graph so the slope of a tangent line should be no different. Why do I get two different expressions for the slope?

Comment: It's quite common for a function to have multiple expressions. Did you put any effort into trying to prove using algebra that those two expressions are either the same or different?

Comment: Keep in mind that $x,y$ are dependent.  They must satisfy the defining equation you started from.  That fact often leads to multiple representations of an implicit derivative.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019620/different-results-implicit-differentiation), among others, for a simple example of this.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @LeeMosher and lulu , this is the direction I am currently looking. Maybe I can use that $xy\sqrt{xy}=x\sqrt x+y\sqrt y$ to simplify the first expression. The second looks much simpler! But technically multiplying both parts by an expression should be fine, right?

Comment: Suppose you have a generic equation $F(x,y)=0,$ where $x'=1,$ $1$ is the multiplicative identity constant function, and $0$ is the additive identity constant function, and $y$ is an arbitrary function we are interested in solving for. Differentiating results in $$F(x,y)'=\frac{\partial{F}(x,y)}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{F}(x,y)}{\partial{y}}y'=0.$$

Comment: On the other hand, if you multiply by $G(x,y)$ first, you obtain $$F(x,y)G(x,y)'+F(x,y)'G(x,y)=F(x,y)\left[\frac{\partial{G}(x,y)}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{G}(x,y)}{\partial{y}}y'\right]+\left[\frac{\partial{F}(x,y)}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{F}(x,y)}{\partial{y}}y'\right]G(x,y)=0.$$ These equations are not expected to be equivalent to.

Comment: For them to be equivalent, it would need to be the case that $$F(x,y)\left[\frac{\partial{G}(x,y)}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{G}(x,y)}{\partial{y}}y'\right]+\left[\frac{\partial{F}(x,y)}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{F}(x,y)}{\partial{y}}y'\right]G(x,y)=F(x,y)'.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simpler example.
$$
f(x,y) = y-x=0,\qquad\text{implies}\qquad g(x,y)=y^2-xy = 0,
$$

so from $f$ we find $y'(x)=1$; from $g$ we find $y'(x)=\frac{y}{2y-x}$, which gives the same answer if $y=x$ but is a different function of $x,y$ in general.

The equation $\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y(x))=0$ allows you to find $y'(x)$ not only on curve $f(x,y)=0$ but on the whole family of curves $f(x,y)=c$ (the same is true for $g$). When $c=0$ both of the families produce the same curve (*). However, in general, they produce different curves, so the slopes of those curves will be different as well.

[image]

(*) in the appropriate region